# Webpack 4 to 5: custom plugin: replacing compilation.assets mutation with compilation.hooks.processAssets

Tags: reactjs, flask, webpack, webpack-5

I am having trouble using the compilation hook `processAssets` to mirror deprecated Webpack 4 functionality in a custom plugin.

The purpose of the plugin is to write the chunkhash for js/css files to a python file, which is used by a Flask server to separate the functionality of the webpage based on a user's session and roles (e.g. public, private, admin, etc).

The meat of the plugin (with direct mutation of the assets) is below.

```
compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync("WriteHashesPlugin", (compilation, cb) => {
    //For each bundle, write the name and the corresponding hash.
    compilation.chunks.forEach(chunk => {
        lines.push("__" + chunk.name + "_hash__ = '" + chunk.renderedHash + "'")
    });
    const content = lines.join("\n");

    compilation.assets[this.filename] = { // <= this.filename = "{relative_path}/bundles.py"
        source: () => content,
        size: () => content.length
    }
    cb();
})
```

This code still "works" to create/update the python file, but of course I don't want to be using deprecated syntax. The warning message in the build output:

```
(node:38072) [DEP_WEBPACK_COMPILATION_ASSETS] DeprecationWarning: Compilation.assets will be frozen in future, all modifications are deprecated.
BREAKING CHANGE: No more changes should happen to Compilation.assets after sealing the Compilation.
        Do changes to assets earlier, e. g. in Compilation.hooks.processAssets.
        Make sure to select an appropriate stage from Compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_*.
```

I have implemented the `compilation.hooks.processAssets` instead of directly accessing the assets; however, I have not been able to get it to work as expected.

```
compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync("WriteHashesPlugin", (compilation, cb) => {
    //For each bundle, write the name and the corresponding hash.
    compilation.chunks.forEach(chunk => {
        lines.push("__" + chunk.name + "_hash__ = '" + chunk.renderedHash + "'")
    });
    const content = lines.join("\n");

    // The below code block compiles but doesn't get run
    compilation.hooks.processAssets.tap({
        name: 'WriteHashesPlugin',
        stage: compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ADDITIONAL,
        additionalAssets: true
    }, () => {
        compilation.emitAsset(
            this.filename,
            content
        );
    });
    cb();
})
```

I've tried using `compilation.updateAsset` with the stage `PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ADDITIONS` as well with no success.

I am not a webpack expert by any means, but have spent the past few days scouring the documentation and attempting to understand the source code. Some ideas I have of what I'm doing wrong:

- `compiler.hooks.emit` is not the appropriate step in the compilation process to be modifying assets (perhaps at a certain point in the compilation process, assets are not to be altered?).
- `compilation.emitAsset` is not the appropriate compilation hook to be using.
- I have misunderstood the deprecation warning in the build output, and I should be doing something completely different.
- There is a better way to make the chunkhashes available to Flask.
- Something else that one of you could illuminate for me.

Comment: I had a similar plugin setup and conversion problem and could solve it for me by using `compiler.hooks.compilation.tap` instead of `compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync`

Comment: @chiborg using `compiler.hooks.compilation.tap` was the first step in getting this to work, thank you! I'll post my solution shortly with appropriate accreditation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @chiborg, I was able to get this code functioning with a few tweaks.

As written in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65535038/webpack-processassets-hook-and-asset-source),

> First, you need to bring in the { sources } class from webpack, which will aid us in crafting raw source changes to an asset (regardless of its optimization or asset type):

```
const { sources } = require('webpack');
```

The appropriate hook to use was `compiler.hooks.compilation.tap` instead of `compiler.hooks.emit.tapAsync`; once that was changed, the rest of the code inside the hook had to be moved into `compilation.hooks.processAssets`:

```
/**
 * Writes build version and bundle hashes to a new file, with the dir
 * specified in this.filename.
 */
compiler.hooks.compilation.tap("WriteHashesPlugin", compilation => {
    compilation.hooks.processAssets.tap({
        name: 'WriteHashesPlugin',
        stage: compilation.PROCESS_ASSETS_STAGE_ADDITIONAL
    }, () => {
        const lines = [];
        // Write build version
        lines.push("__version__ = '" + this.version + "'");
        // For each bundle, write the name and the corresponding hash.
        compilation.chunks.forEach(chunk => {
            lines.push("__" + chunk.name + "_hash__ = '" + chunk.renderedHash + "'");
        });
        const content = lines.join("\n");
        // write bundles.py to assets
        compilation.emitAsset(
            this.filename,
            new sources.RawSource(content)
        );
    });
});
```

`compilation.chunks` was empty when accessed outside the `processAssets` hook, but moving everything into the hook made it work as expected.

Comment: Instead of `const { sources } = require('webpack');` I would recommend using: `const sources = compilation.compiler.webpack.sources;` to make sure you're referencing the same Webpack instance that is actually running your plugin. This avoids headaches/bugs/difficult debugging if there happens to be multiple versions of Webpack in your `node_modules` and your plugin will work with pnpm/yarn/npm symlinks.